# Kafka Connect with MSSQL doesn't work for delete operations

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using Kafka Connect with [Confluent MSSQL connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql/) on SQL Server 2014. I tried insert and update operations and they work correctly, pushing the correct record to Kafka. If I delete a record I receive this on the Kafka topic:

```
{"schema":null,"payload":null}
```

I expect instead the details of the deleted records.

I enabled CDC with the following commands:

```
ALTER DATABASE WebAppDb SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON) 
GO 
ALTER DATABASE WebAppDb SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON 
GO 
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
GO
```

Comment: Which connector are you using? There are several connectors out there that will work with MS SQL

Answer (score 1):

I would check the connector and MSSQL Server version in use since according to the Confluent website for the [Kafka Connect Microsoft SQL Server Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-cdc-mssql/index.html)

> Change Data Capture is a feature that is only available on SQL Server Enterprise and Developer editions

Then check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044641/delete-events-from-jdbc-kafka-connect-source?rq=1) and the info fomr the [Debezium Connector for SQL Server](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/sqlserver/).
It looks like the issue may still have to be implemented since it's still [open on Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/310)

Comment: I'm using Express edition. anyway I don't understand why create and update operations work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually representing a delete message, if your payload is null this means the record was deleted, what you can do now is check the message `key` and do the desired deletion in your consumer.

The payload as you see is for now indeed wrong, there was a bug in Kafka Connect which was unabling the Json conversion to produce `tombstone` messages, that's why you see it like this"

```
{"schema":null,"payload":null}
```

When the bug fix is release your message should have a `null` body, but you can act the same way about the deletion in both cases.

[More about the bug here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3832)

[More about tombstone messages here](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-log-compaction/index.html)

Comment: I updated to the latest Kafka Confluent version 5.1.0 (Kafka 2.1.0-cp1) but I still receive `{"schema":null,"payload":null}` as message in my consumer for delete operations.

Comment: Hello @AlessandroDionisi, since 2.1.0 was already released I think you'll have to wait for 2.2.0, unless you want to test with a nightly build (I don't know if those are available but you can try to check it)